# Why is a thicker boundary layer more turbulent?

Tags: aerodynamics, fluid-mechanics

Why is a thicker boundary layer more turbulent? I’m mainly referring to the effect of the varying speed over the boundary layer, and why it makes it more turbulent. I know it has something to do with the Reynolds number, but what happens physically to make a turbulent boundary layer?

Answer (score 1):

A [boundary layer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/37760/what-is-boundary-layer-exactly/37787#37787) starts at thickness zero and grows from there. Since the transition from laminar to turbulent flow can be anywhere between the start of the boundary layer and a local Reynolds number of several million, turbulent layers tend to occur when the boundary layer has already reached some thickness. Turbulent boundary layers will not go back to a laminar state, so the thickest part is almost always turbulent (except for small Reynolds numbers which on the external surfaces can only be found on small model airplanes - there, a boundary layer can stay laminar until its separation).

Next, turbulence lets a boundary layer [grow more quickly](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/86527/how-does-the-turbulent-boundary-layer-thickness-affect-separation/86546#86546) than laminar flow. Actually, the question should be reversed: A turbulent boundary layer is thicker.

Comment: Oh okay, I see, thanks. One small question : why do boundary layers turn turbulent as they travel over a wing/surface?

Comment: I edited my question to capture more of what I really was asking, so that might help to see where I am at.

Comment: @Wyatt You should really ask a new question instead of re-writing one that has already an existing answer. Now the answer is off-topic.

Comment: I just realized that, thanks for pointing that out. I'll edit it back and ask a separate question for that.

Answer (score 1):

A short answer to the question is: Viscosity.

Boundary layer is absolutely a viscous phenomenon, it arises due to "friction" between fluid (air) and surface of the wing, this might be thought of as the moving air loses some of its energy while contacting the surface, so some of the velocity is gradually lost..

When you say "varying speed over the boundary layer", if you mean the gradual vertical decrease in velocity, this is because the rate of change of velocity with respect to height over the surface is linearly proportional to the shear stress that appears due to friction, according to this law:
$\tau = \mu \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$

Where $\tau$, the shear stress, is typically a positive value (in direction of positive x-axis), so the velocity $u$ increases gradually as height above the surface increase, until the velocity equals the freestream velocity $u=u_{\infty}$.

This is also explained in the image:
[image: Image from NASA]

Comment: Oh okay. But why does the pressure gradient make turbulence?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, I believe the main answer is still: viscosity, and hence, friction,
I think it's intuitive to think of it this way: if an airfoil is extremely smooth, streamlines of air would move on a path exactly on the surface of the airfoil, taking exactly its shape, this is called a laminar flow.

Comment: Friction on the other side, causes changes in the air flow, streamlines exchange velocity with each other, both velocity and direction of streamlines changes in a chaotic manner. That's why there's no theory that actually models turbulence as far as I know until today, because it's chaos.
This is how I think of it, it might not be very accurate physical explanation, but it's just my intuition and I hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks for your intuition! There's also another [question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/102684/70478) I asked here that got some good answers.

Comment: Thank you, by the way when I said: streamlines exchange velocity, this is not accurate, I meant layers of air above the airfoil change velocity, but anyway you got the point

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for pointing that out!